# HTML code in liferay session message

Tags: html, liferay, liferay-6, portlet, message

I'm trying to add a customized success message to my Liferay 6.1 portlet. It's supposed to include a `<ul>` list with details about the action performed.

I tried `SessionMessages.add(actionRequest,"request_processed","This is the list: <ul><li>item</li></ul>");` but in the browser (tested Chrome and FireFox) it shows as text:

`<ul><li>item</li></ul>`

The tags aren't lost, they simply show up as if they were normal text. If I edit the content in the browser (e.g. with Firebug) and simply add a space somewhere the browser seems to notice that there are HTML tags and shows the list:

- item

It feels like I should use another way to get HTML in there but I can't see it.

Comment: One workaround, you can use SessionMessages.contains(PortletRequest portletRequest, String key) method to check if message is there and based on that show html part. e.g. `<c:if test='<%=SessionMessages.contains(renderRequest, "key") %>'>
 "This is the list: <ul><li>item</li></ul>"
</c:if>`

Comment: I've done something similar now. I passed the message from the action to the render phase and then put it in a `<liferay-ui:success>` tag. It works but it still feels like there should be a better way to do this.